# Does humidity matter for ageing wine in screw top bottles

Tags: wine, storage

Nearly all articles about ageing wine say it is important to control the humidity.

However if you try to find out why the answers are all about preventing the cork from drying out.

Here in New Zealand/Australia we have long abandoned corks for screw top bottles.

Are there reasons to control the humidity if you are ageing in screw top bottles?

Answer (score 4):

No it does not. When it comes to screw caps, the things important to keep away from aging wine in a screwcap bottle are light, heat and motion. If oxygen can't penetrate the cap, how could humidity? Just keep it out of light and keep it cool.